# Can you help me understand what a "lyrical short story" is?

Tags: plot, short-story, narrative, poetry

What are the minimum requirements for a lyrical short story to be a story? If it is plotless what separates the lyrical short story from random chatter?

Comment: Lyrical short story: https://studylib.net/doc/6677412/fact-sheet_lyric-short-story https://www.slaphappylarry.com/two-types-short-stories/

Comment: Of the eight questions you've posted prior to this one, you've self-deleted five (and this is a repost of one of those questions, albeit edited). I'd just like to let you know that if you have too many deleted questions, you'll eventually trigger an automated question ban and be limited to one question every six months. I'm not privy to the details of SE's question-ban algorithm, but I do know that it considers deleted questions to be an indicator of low quality. Please think very carefully before deleting any future questions.

Comment: Eventually you will get to **"What is a story?"** I suggest you skip ahead and work on that definition.... You will never define these split-hairs until you can identify the fundamentals.

Comment: A story is a telling of an event. So what is a lyrical short story? A story lacking the lengthy plots found in novels?

Comment: A newspaper 'tells an event'. A history book also 'tells an event'. (to be really pedantic, a train schedule 'tells an event')…. These things aren't 'stories' though. Stories (that touch us) are more than a series of plot events….

Comment: This seems to be a big philosophical question along the lines of "What is the difference between art and non-art?" And it's not clear how to answer this in a Stack Exchange post. Maybe you could make it more concrete and focus on examples. It's clear from the links you provide that a lyrical short story exists in a certain space where story and plot are less important than poetic expression, but it's impossible to provide firm boundaries or a firm rule to say "this is poetry".